# Как вставить переменную php в тело запроса json

Tags: php

Вопрос - как вставить переменную php в тело запроса json?

```
public function sender() {
    $this->load->model('novaPoshta/novaPoshta');
    $api_key = $this->model_novaPoshta_novaPoshta->get_api();
    $key = ($api_key['api_key']);

    $json = '{
        "apiKey":" $key" ,
        "modelName": "Counterparty",
        "calledMethod": "getCounterparties",
        "methodProperties": {
            "CounterpartyProperty": "Sender",
            "Page": "1"
        }
    }';

    $sender = $this->sendRequest($json);

    return $sender;
}
```

Таким образом получаю ошибку. Если вставить ключ, то все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, в одинарных кавычках нельзя ставить переменные. В в двойных придется экранировать кавычки в теле запроса, потому проще сделать через конкатенацию.

```
public function sender(){
    $this->load->model('novaPoshta/novaPoshta');
    $api_key = $this->model_novaPoshta_novaPoshta->get_api();
    $key = ($api_key['api_key']);

    $json = '{
                "apiKey":" ' . $key . '" ,
                "modelName": "Counterparty",
                "calledMethod": "getCounterparties",
                "methodProperties": {
                    "CounterpartyProperty": "Sender",
                    "Page": "1"
                }
            }';
    $sender = $this->sendRequest($json);

    return $sender;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь теперь все работает

Answer (score 2):

> Как вставить переменную php в тело запроса json

```
public function sender(){
    $this->load->model('novaPoshta/novaPoshta');
    $api_key = $this->model_novaPoshta_novaPoshta->get_api();
    $json = array(
        'apiKey'=>$api_key['api_key'],
        'modelName'=>'Counterparty',
        'calledMethod'=>'getCounterparties',
        'methodProperties'=>array(
            'CounterpartyProperty'=>'Sender',
            'Page'=>1
        )
    );
    return $this->sendRequest(json_encode($json));
}
```